# How to sketch a curve given its equation?

Tags: calculus

I am given the equation of a curve which is $y = x(x-2)^2 $ and I am asked to sketch that curve.

What I've already done: I already found the stationary points of the curve by differentiating the equation and I got $(2,0) $ and $(2/3, 32/27) $ and I found the nature of the two stationary points and the result is when $x=2 $, its a minimum and when $x=2/3$ , its a maximum.

What do I do next?

Comment: Next you can apply information on what polynomials of third degree look like in general. In this case, the function approaches positive infinity for large positive values of $x$, and negative infinity for large negative values of $x$.

Comment: It would be useful to find limits $\to \infty$

Comment: You may use some grapf calculators like desmos,  to have a clear view.

Comment: I would solve the the equation $$x(x-2)^2=0$$ for $x$

Comment: If you follow Sonnhard's advice, you will find that the $x$-intercepts are $0$ and $2$.  You should examine the sign of $y = x(x - 2)^2$ in the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$, $(0, 2)$, and $(2, \infty)$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks, I now understand what to do. Thanks alot sir.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $y=x(x-2)^2$ has zeros at $x=0$ and at $x=2$.

Let's look at the important attributes of the graph of $y(x)$ moving from left to right.

When $x <0$ then $y <0$ so the graph starts in the lower left hand quadrant.

At $x=0$ you know that $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=4$ which is positive, so at $(0,0)$ the graph of $y(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis from the lower left hand quadrant into the upper right hand quadrant.

You then have a maximum at $(2/3, 32/27)$ so the graph is horizontal at that point. As you move from left to right the graph stops going upwards at $(2/3, 32/27)$ and heads downwards.

At $(2,0)$ you have a root *and* a minimum (this is because of the factor of $(x-2)^2$), so here the graph just touches the $x$-axis as it comes down from $(2/3, 32/27)$, but then turns upwards again.

When $x >2$ then $y >0$ so the graph ends in the upper right hand quadrant.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you very much, really clear explanation !

Answer (score 2):

given the curve $y=x(x-2)^2$

As you have said the best way to start would be to check for a few things:

1. asymptotes
2. discontinuities
3. stationary points
4. roots (points at which it crosses the axis)

First of all, for all real $x$, $y$ is also real so this function can be kept in just the real range.

Roots to this equation are easy to find as it has already been factorised, so we can easily see the points $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$ for where it crosses the $x$ axis. We can already see from our first root that this function passes through the origin, so we already know where it crosses the $y$ axis.

We can clearly see that there are no usable asymptotes as $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\infty$. We also know that it is a continuous, non-periodic function.

To find the stationary points we just differentiate:

$$y=x(x-2)^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x-2)^2+2x(x-2)$$
let $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and solve for $x$

we get:
$$(x-2)(3x-2)=0$$
and so the $x$ values for our stationary points are:
$x=2$ and $x=\frac{2}{3}$

we now input each of these into our function to find the points:
$$f(2)=2(2-2)^2=0$$
$$f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}-2\right)^2=\frac{32}{27}$$

so now we have the points $(2,0)$ and $\left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{32}{27}\right)$

we can see that one of our roots is repeated $(x-2)^2$ and it is also a stationary point. This suggests to us that the line 'touches' this point twice and therefore it must not pass the axis here.

When we check we can see that $f(2.1)=0.021$ so the line approaches this point from above. We also know that this curve has two distinct roots and is a cubic where the coefficient of the $x^3$ term is positive so is must form an S shape, coming from negative below $x=0$ and tending to infinity for x>0, so we can plot the points we know and draw this characteristic curve through them.

Hope this helps

Comment: Very good answer. I'll just add that, more than stationary points, it is useful to find the intervals where the functions is increasing, and the intervals where it is decreasing. Also, checking symmetry (even? odd? periodic?) at the beginning may help study the function.

Comment: That is a good point yes, sometimes it can also help to find the second derivative too and see for which values it is positive or negative, as this tells you when the gradient of the desired line is increasing or decreasing

Answer (score 1):

That's already really good, now try to draw these points inside a coordinate system.

Then it might be helpful to expand the equation into $y = x^3-4x^2+4x$ which tells you two things: First, the curve goes through the origin, and second, it has degree $3$.

Such curves have a very characteristic shape: As the maximum comes first (reading from the left), the  curve will come from $-\infty$, pass through the origin, go up to the maximum, then drop down to the minimum, and then go up into $+\infty$.

Spoiler: This is what it looks like: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+x(x-2)%5E2

Comment: How did you obtain a negative leading coefficient?

Comment: Incorrect expansion, I've submitted an edit correcting it

Comment: I guess its not necessary to expand it because we could just equate x to 0 and (x-2)^2 to zero, yes? Thanks though.